# What's happening if we vacuum an air that exists inside aclosed system?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, vacuum

Excuse me, I have a closed system and wanted to vacuum an air that exists inside it, so what is happening with temperature inside that system ? Is it increase or decrease ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the air from a closed system ?  Because if you can remove it, it is not closed.

Comment: Since temperature is defined as the energy of the particles of the system in some sense, a perfect vacuum cannot lacks of temperature in a classical fashion.

Comment: yes, I can remove the air from that system by air compressor, so are you thinking that temperature is increase or decrease ? @stephenG

Comment: Why not the temperature decreases , because i remove that particles from this system  ,I know it's difficult to remove it completely . @Alejandro Menaya

Comment: If you remove the air in a rigid container, the pressure will decrease at the same rate as the air does (assuming ideal conditions) jn a real situation the temperature will decrease. But at some point there sill be not enough material for a sensible macroscopic concept of temperature.

Comment: Is this a theoretical question about the impact of removing a quantity of air from a chamber (partially evacuate) or are you actually talking about using a compressor to remove air from a chamber?

Comment: Yes, I just want to know what's happening in my system about( temperature ) ,is it increase or decrease? If we remove the air from this system. @Bob D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Nashwan's last clarification that he is simply removing air (and assuming no heat transfer involved) I suggest the following answer:

Since temperature is a measure of the average translational kinetic energy of the air molecules in the system, if we remove some of the molecules we also remove the kinetic energy possessed by those molecules. Ergo the temperature of the remaining gas should be less.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nashwan, upon further reflection I believe the temperature will remain the same. Although removing air molecules lowers the total internal (kinetic) energy of the remaining molecules, there are also fewer molecules sharing that energy. Thus the average translational kinetic energy per remaining molecule should be the same.  The pressure, however, will decrease, as there will be fewer molecules striking the sides of the container per unit time. From the ideal gas law:

$$pV = mRT$$

$$T = \frac{pV}{mR}$$

Where m is the mass of air and R is the specific gas constant for air. If T and V are constant, then the ratio of pressure to mass is constant. If we lower mass, we proportionally lower pressure.

Sorry about that.